# Serilog MSSqlServer table schema

Tags: configuration, serilog

Is there any way to change the default schema to something other than dbo?
I am developing a CORE 2.0 web api and using MSSqlServer as sink. Tried adding "Schema": "Log" in the appsettings.json file, and it does not work.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Use schemaName property in configuration

"Args": {
            "connectionString": ***,
            "tableName": "Logs",
            "schemaName": "aclibi"
          }

https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver/issues/63

Answer (score 0):

The MSSqlServer sink can take an optional parameter "schemaName":

```
 Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
     .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(connectionString, "MyLogs", schemaName: "myschema")
     .CreateLogger();
```

See the MSSqlServer sink [configuration options](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver#sink-configuration-options) documentation for more information.